# Woocommerce - Get meta data from product ordered

Tags: php, mysql, woocommerce

I want to get the meta data (_wcj_purchase_price) of products from the complete orders since one month.

I try with MYSQL and WP_Query, but I qickly lost with that.

Actually, I have the meta_value for the product :

`SELECT post_id as order_id, meta_key, meta_value from wp_postmeta where post_id in
         ( SELECT ID FROM`wp_posts
           `WHERE post_type = 'shop_order' and post_date BETWEEN NOW() - INTERVAL 30 DAY AND NOW()
          )

and meta_key  = '_wcj_purchase_price'`

But I don't know to get this value for each product ordered.

Answer (score 1):

With the help of @dan-webb I have this result :

`SELECT post_id as order_id, meta_key, meta_value from wp_postmeta where post_id in
         ( SELECT ID FROM`wp_posts
           `WHERE post_type = 'shop_order' and post_date BETWEEN NOW() - INTERVAL 30 DAY AND NOW()
          )

and meta_key  = '_wcj_purchase_price'`

But it's return the product meta and not the product ordered.

Comment: So you have the '_wcj_purchase_price' value but you also need the name of the product ordered?

Comment: It's for all orders

Answer (score 0):

The MySQL way would be:

```
SELECT post_id as order_id, meta_key, meta_value from wp_postmeta where post_id in
         ( SELECT ID FROM `wp_posts`  
           WHERE post_type = 'shop_order' and post_date BETWEEN NOW() - INTERVAL 30 DAY AND NOW()
          )                                         
and meta_key  = '_wcj_purchase_price'
```

Comment: Thanks ! But the meta is in wp_postmeta table and not wp_woocommerce_order_itemmeta

Comment: Is the post that its associated with 'shop_order' posts or 'product' posts?

Comment: It's 'shop order'

Comment: Not work for me. I think the problem is the 'post_id' of '_wcj_purchase_price' is the '_product_id' in wp_woocommerce_order_item_meta

Comment: Try replacing 'shop_order' with 'product'

Comment: Yes it works, but I get the meta for the product et and not for the ordered products :/

Comment: add the results of the query to your question along with the desired data that you wish to return. I am unable to continue helping without more information

Comment: Thanks a lot ! 

This is what I want : 
For each product ordered, get the meta_value of '_wcj_purchase_price'.

This value is in wp_postmeta and link with the post_id of the product and not of the order. 

I don't know if you need another information, sorry :/